# IOException not caught

Tags: java, android, exception, try-catch

i have the catch block as below

```
try {
                // the function that can throw exception

            } catch (InterruptedException | InterruptedIOException e) {
                return false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error ", e);

                failure++;
            }
```

But if an IOException is thrown its not caught and the app is crashing.
I assume it to be caught by the second catch

Comment: It will get caught by this second `Exception` catch block. as long as the second `Exception` is `java.lang.Exception`. with given information it is impossible to believe you. paste some more of the code. I suspect catch part of code of yours is also throwing an exception

Comment: i have edited the code. Its 2 catch block for the same try and Exception is Java.lang.Exception

Answer (score 1):

you should try to write just:

```
catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println(e);
 }
```

Comment: I need to do different action if it is a interrupted exception

Comment: when you do it with just : "catch(Exception e) ", does it still crash ? if no, then the error is neither "InterruptedException" nor "InterruptedIOException"